# ubuntu GUI on Docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

i am new to docker  I'm using it because i have a  project with some dependencies and i need to speed up the process of running the code on another machine.

my python code will run about 3 commands :

```
1-  python run.py -s example
2- python run.py - k example 
....
```

it's a selenium project so i need Firefox and web-driver plus python 3.9 specifically .

after watching some tutorials; some install Ubuntu on the container ; some begin using the container

so my best option is to download Ubuntu on docker with GUI.
right?
if so can someone guide me because i can't find a tutorial for it .